# TailwindCSS - Applied styles removed in production

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[UPDATE 28-9-2021]

What I also did to eliminate other causes: Update OS packages (Centos 8), rebuilt Apache / NGINX, rebuilt NPM modules, updated and rebuilt TailwindCSS, tried default config files / json files, but all these didn't give me any result :-( I'm really stuck here

[/UPDATE]

Maybe I'm overlooking something here.
I added some basic styling to my *style.css* for headings:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {

  p {
    @apply text-theme-gray-lighter pb-4;
  }
  h1 {
    @apply text-3xl py-2;
  }
  h2 {
    @apply text-2xl py-2 border-b mb-2;
  }
  h3 {
    @apply text-xl py-1 font-semibold text-theme-blue;
  }
  h4 {
    @apply text-lg font-semibold;
  }
  h3.price {
    @apply text-theme-gray;
  }
  .boks-bold {
    @apply font-semibold p-4 px-6 text-lg m-4 my-6 mt-2 border shadow-md rounded;
  }
}
```

This file is located at the root of my project.

This is my tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    extend: {
      grayscale: ['hover', 'focus'],
      backgroundColor: ['checked'],
      borderColor: ['checked'],
      borderColor: ['focus-within'],
    }
  },
  darkMode: 'media',
  purge: ["*.jsx", "*.js", "*.php"],
  plugins: [
      // require('daisyui'),
      // require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
      require('@tailwindcss/custom-forms'),
  ],
  daisyui: {
    // styled: false,
    // themes: false,
    // rtl: false,
  },
  theme: {

    customForms: theme => ({
      default: {
        'input, textarea, multiselect, checkbox, radio': {
          borderdColor: theme('colors.gray.200'),
        },
      },
    }),

    container: {
      padding: '1rem',
      center: true,
    },
    extend: {
      width: {
        'full-150': '150vw',
        'full-200': '200vw',
      },
      height: {
        '18': '4.5rem',
        '40rem': '40rem',
        '730px': '730px',
        '650px': '650px',
        '1191px': '1191px',
        '901px': '901px',
        '722px': '722px',
        '110perc': '110%',
      },
      maxHeight: {
      '110perc': '110%',
      },
      zIndex: {
        '-10': '-10',
      },
      borderWidth: {
        '12': '12px',
      },
      colors: {
        'theme-brown': '#BF8A23',
        'theme-yellow': '#FAA71B',
        'theme-brown-brighter': '#DDB15B',
        'theme-gray': '#333333',
        'theme-gray-lighter': '#444444',
        'theme-blue': '#547A82',
      },
      minWidth: {
        '0': '0',
        '1/4': '25%',
        '1/2': '50%',
        '3/4': '75%',
        'full': '100%',
       },
       animation: {
         'scroll-rtl-slow': 'scrollbrand scroll 40s linear infinite',
       },
       keyframes: {
        scrollbrand: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
          '100%': { transform: 'translateX(calc(-250px * 7))',
          }
        }
       }
    }
  }
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "daisyui": "^1.10.0",
    "node-cron": "2.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.6",
    "vue-tailwind": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build -i style.css -o css/style.css",
    "build": "tailwindcss style.css -o css/style.css",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss css/style.css -o css/style.min.css"
  },
  "name": "templateh.sceneryworkshop.com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "tailwind.config.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "^0.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.52.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

To get the **@apply** working, I had to add **-i** to the command:

```
*"build-css": "tailwindcss build -i style.css -o css/style.css"*
```

But when I do the same when building production:

```
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss -i css/style.css -o css/style.min.css"
```

The file doesn't get purged at all, so it keeps it's total size.

Anyone who has an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I actually can't seem to reproduce this. I have created a similar environment in a [codesandbox.io container](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-davinci-11c09?file=/css/style.min.css). If you run `npm run build` it'll build it but it won't show it because it's too large of a file but if you run `npm run production` it'll build and you can see the resulting css file only has the normalize styles and the `ml-2` that I used in the `index.jsx` file

Comment: I see the correct results in your example :-) But ... that doesn't point me in any right direction unfortunately :-(

Comment: Can you show us any part of a PHP file that has tailwind classes in it? Tailwind has some simple rules for making sure that classes can be purged so I just want to verify that your styling meets that criteria. Also, can you try setting the [purge option to enabled manually](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#enabling-manually) and run the `build` command to make sure that the issue is not with the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add path to your config file in your command:

```
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss -c ./tailwind.config.js -i css/style.css -o css/style.min.css"
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but I don't think the problem I'm running into has something to do with that. I have all files in the root, except JS (./scripts) - which I added to the config now and the final CSS files (./css). Should I purge *.css or ./css/*.css also? I never read about it, but maybe it should

Comment: And where are your `jsx` files placed? To purge correctly you have to put correct location of files that use tailwind classes. For example, `php` file which renders html should be pointed in this config.

Comment: I don't use JSX / React. Also, the php files are in the root. So no src, dist folders or something.

Comment: Then I don't understand why do you have `jsx` file in purgelist. I think I've found your problem - check my answer.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I'm really happy with your efford! The purge settings are the default ones, that's why JSX is there. Everything works, but when I provide the -i parameter, the CSS isn't purged so the file is as big as default. When I remove the -i parameter, the file size is 33kb, but then the @applied styles (h1, h2 etc.) are removed. Everything else is working as expected.

Comment: Try using new tailwindcss-cli `npx tailwindcss -i ./css/style.css -c ./tailwind.config.js -o ./css/style.min.css`

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Kokot, but this gives me the same output:
https://i.imgur.com/n9XOD1E.png
No purging unfortunately :-(

Comment: And have you tried the command above with `NODE_ENV=production`? Like this: `NODE_ENV=production npx tailwindcss -i ./css/style.css -c ./tailwind.config.js -o ./css/style.min.css`?

Comment: Unfortunately the same result. What I also did to eliminate other causes: Update OS packages (Centos 8), rebuilt Apache / NGINX, rebuilt NPM modules, updated and rebuilt TailwindCSS, tried default config files / json files, but all these didn't give me any result :-( I'm really stuck here

Comment: post your directory structure, content of your files. From files that you've posted I cannot even reproduce the error.